# How to install packages offline with Ubuntu 22.04 Server Autoinstall

Tags: 22.04, autoinstall

I am making a custom ISO w/ autoinstall to automatically install Ubuntu Server onto our machines. We of course need to install some apt packages as part of the customization. The problem is, this installation needs to be done entirely offline, so I can't just add them to the apt package list and have subiquity magic take care of everything.

I am using [this method](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/ubuntu-22-04-server-autoinstall-iso/) to pack the user-install/autoinstall file into the iso and that is working well.

How can I download apt packages ahead of time, include them on the iso, and have subiquity automatically find and install them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this [here](https://trustlesscustody.com/2023/09/11/how-to-install-apt-packages-offline-with-ubuntu-22-04-server-autoinstall/)

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the the internal apt repository on the iso.

Deb files are located in pool/main.
The manifest of deb files is dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz.
SHA256 summary is in dists/focal/Release.

Last problem is that installation checks the signing of the Release file.
Usually it is signed by Ubuntu.
There are 2 potential ways to solve it:

1. To set `deb [trusted=yes] file:///cdrom focal main` so it won't check gpg sign. But I don't know where this is located in the ISO.
2. To use your own key to sign it and add the pubkey to trusted keys in ISO.
   After modifying them, you can use packages section in user-data as with network.

   The full steps with signing the Release:

   1. Extract iso. I'll call the extracted dir 'iso'.
   2. Add the packages to `iso/pool/main/path/to/package.deb`. You can use

      ```
      url=$(apt-get download --print-uris "$package" | awk '{print $1}')
      ```

      This will give you the source so you can download it in the same order as the original repository.
3. Then to add them to the Packages.gz file that lists all the available packages by calling

   ```
   PACKAGES_FILE_PATH="main/binary-amd64/Packages"
   PACKAGES_GZ_FILE_PATH="main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz"
   # Create Packages file
   cd iso
   dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null > dists/focal/$PACKAGES_FILE_PATH
   cd dists/focal
   # Compress Packages file into Packages.gz
   gzip -9c $PACKAGES_FILE_PATH > $PACKAGES_GZ_FILE_PATH
   ```
4. Update the the Release file:

   ```
   # Update Release file with new sha256 and size
   PACKAGES_INFO=$(apt-ftparchive release . | grep --after-context=10 SHA256 | grep "$PACKAGES_FILE_PATH" | head -n 1)
   PACKAGES_GZ_INFO=$(apt-ftparchive release . | grep --after-context=10 SHA256 | grep "$PACKAGES_GZ_FILE_PATH")
   # Update the Release file with new values
   sed -i "\@$PACKAGES_FILE_PATH@ s@.*@$PACKAGES_INFO@" Release
   sed -i "\@$PACKAGES_GZ_FILE_PATH@ s@.*@$PACKAGES_GZ_INFO@" Release
   ```
5. Create a gpg key and sign the Release file:

   ```
   GPG_KEY_EMAIL="your.email@example.com"  # Replace with your email address
   # Check if GPG key exists; if not, generate a new one
   if ! gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG "$GPG_KEY_EMAIL" &> /dev/null; then
       echo "Generating a new GPG key..."
       gpg --batch --gen-key <<EOF
       %echo Generating a GPG key
       Key-Type: RSA
       Key-Length: 4096
       Subkey-Type: RSA
       Subkey-Length: 4096
       Name-Real: Your Name
       Name-Email: $GPG_KEY_EMAIL
       Expire-Date: 0
       Passphrase: YourPassphrase
       %commit
       %echo done
   EOF
   fi
   rm -f iso/dists/focal/Release.gpg
   # Sign the Release file with GPG
   gpg --batch --passphrase "ubuntu" --default-key "$GPG_KEY_EMAIL" -abs -o iso/dists/focal/Release.gpg iso/dists/focal/Release
   ```
6. Add the public key (gpg) to trusted keys in filesystem.squashfs.

   ```
   sudo unsquashfs -d filesystem iso/casper/filesystem.squashfs
   gpg --export $GPG_KEY_EMAIL > autoinstall.gpg
   sudo mv autoinstall.gpg filesystem/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
   sudo rm iso/casper/filesystem.squashfs
   sudo mksquashfs filesystem/ iso/casper/filesystem.squashfs -comp xz -e boot
   sudo rm -rf filesystem/
   ```