# How to optimize installation process during offline autoinstall Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, offline, autoinstall

I'm a beginner in Ubuntu and I'm trying to create offline autoinstall for Ubuntu 22.04.

I followed [this link](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/ubuntu-22-04-server-autoinstall-iso/#Conclusion) at first to create the autoinstall and succeeded in doing so. However, since I need this autoinstall to work on PC without OS and internet connection, the autoinstall that I've created doesn't work.

Then I found [this](https://trustlesscustody.com/2023/09/11/how-to-install-apt-packages-offline-with-ubuntu-22-04-server-autoinstall/) link from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1483970/how-to-install-packages-offline-with-ubuntu-22-04-server-autoinstall) but during the autoinstall, the late commands for installing the packages are taking too long to install the packages. I want to install ubuntu-desktop package so that I can get the graphical interface for Ubuntu 22.04.

[This is how it looks like during the autoinstall (for reference).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoXxl.png) I was waiting close to 30 minutes for this. Thank you in advance for helping me.

Edit: I'm installing on a VirtualBox VM with 4506 MB Base Memory and 45GB storage, and my network connection speed is around 80Mbps. My laptop has a 256GB storage with 8GB RAM, which might be relevant. Can you provide tips to optimize the installation process based on these details? Your insights would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I've included my user-data and chroot_script.sh files below.

user-data file:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  locale: en_US.UTF-8
  keyboard:
    layout: us
  identity:
    hostname: user
    username: user
    password: crypted_password
  late-commands:
    - rm -r /target/var/cache/apt
    - cp -r /media/minimal/var/cache/apt /target/var/cache/
    - curtin in-target --target /target -- apt-get -yy install ubuntu-desktop
```

chroot_script.sh

```
mount -t proc none /proc
mount -t sysfs none /sys
mount -t devpts none /dev/pts
apt-get -y update
apt-get -yyqq install --download-only ubuntu-desktop
umount /proc
umount /sys
umount /dev/pts
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1490821/edit) to add new information and refine your ask. Please avoid commenting on your own question.

Comment: Please update your question with the contents of your `user-data` file and the `chroot_script.sh` script that the tutorial references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was successfully able to follow the tutorial you provided and create a custom Ubuntu 22.04 Server ISO to install additional software as indicated in an offline situation. For example, I created an ISO that installed a package called `nala`. However, I was unsuccessful when attempting to install `gnome-desktop` as you desire. During the installation, the process stalled at the same point as you, and after two hours, I gave up and stopped the installation. With a total number of 1323 packages downloaded for `ubuntu-desktop`, this is a lot of packages to install. (BTW, this total can be seen by looking in the `var/cache/apt/archives/` directory in the *edit* folder that you've chrooted into and run the `chroot_script.sh` shell script.)

So this process works, but I think the `gnome-desktop` package and dependencies are simply too large and too many to realistically install in this manner in a VM. Perhaps an installation on bare metal instead of a VirtualBox VM would be different, but I didn't try.

---

Now with that said, what I'm actually gathering from your question is that you ultimately want a Desktop installation, but you want to take advantage of *autoinstall*. If so, there is another alternative to creating an *autoinstall* of Ubuntu Desktop. This technique is similar to the above, except that you're actually adding the squashfs filesystem from the Ubuntu Desktop ISO to the Server ISO instead of installing the `ubuntu-desktop` package into the Server installation. With this technique, *Subiquity* from the Server ISO is used for the installation of everything.

The basic steps (very loosely outlined) are as follows:

- Unpack Server ISO to a directory (for example: `server-iso-extracted`)
- Unpack Desktop ISO to a directory (for example: `desktop-iso-extracted`)
- If needed or desired:

  - Unsquash `desktop-iso-extracted/casper/filesystem.squashfs` from Desktop ISO
  - chroot into it
  - Run any custom scripts
  - Re-squash `filesystem.squashfs`
- Copy re-squashed `filesystem.squashfs` to the unpacked Server ISO directory into: `server-iso-extracted/casper/filesystem.squashfs`
- Add `user-data` and `meta-data` files to sub-directory in unpacked Server ISO directory. For example: `server-iso-extracted/nocloud/`
- Update `grub.cfg` for autoinstall, which is found in `server-iso-extracted/boot/grub/grub.cfg`
- Update `server-iso-extracted/casper/install-sources.yaml` in the unpacked Server ISO directory to use `filesystem.squashfs` for installation.
- Repack Server ISO

A working `user-data` file for this technique is as follows:

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  # The following credentials will create a default user. username: ubuntu - password: ubuntu 
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu-desktop
    password: $6$5lpwCLsKLEzMkSJc$keOAhA6aO/5RocGThmhVA7LSNuW911Rx5HHXFEa75oGK20cEdAAgn14H5f5nGeq6QgcSyLPrWcg1.JvjXbhrN/
    realname: Ubuntu user
    username: ubuntu
  user-data:
    timezone: America/Los_Angeles
  # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
  network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
  refresh-installer:
    update: no
  keyboard:
    layout: us
    toggle: null
    variant: ''
  locale: en_US.UTF-8
# cloud-init is not installed by default in the Desktop ISO. Therefore, it either needs to be installed within the ISO or installed with the following lines:
#  late-commands:
#  - curtin in-target --target=/target -- apt install -y cloud-init
```

A working `casper/install-sources.yaml` is as follows:

```
- description:
    en: This version installs a Desktop environment
      where humans are not expected to log in.
  id: desktop 
  locale_support: none
  name:
    en: Ubuntu Desktop
  path: filesystem.squashfs
  size: 568651776
  type: fsimage
  variant: server
  default: true
```

A working `boot/grub/grub.cfg` file is as follows:

```
set timeout=30

loadfont unicode

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

menuentry "Try or Install Ubuntu Server" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz   autoinstall  ds=nocloud\;s=/cdrom/nocloud/ ---
    initrd  /casper/initrd
}
grub_platform
if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
menuentry 'Boot from next volume' {
    exit 1
}
menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' {
    fwsetup
}
else
menuentry 'Test memory' {
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
fi
```

The above info and steps were gathered from the scripts at the following link:

- [Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop Autoinstall](https://github.com/michaeltandy/ubuntu-desktop-22.04-autoinstall)

  Michael Tandy is the author, and I've used his script. It works, but I found one discrepancy. In his `user-data` file, he writes the following, which indicates the *user/password* credentials have no effect:

> ```
> # The following credentials have no effect - the user will be set up by gnome-initial-setup
> password: $6$5lpwCLsKLEzMkSJc$keOAhA6aO/5RocGThmhVA7LSNuW911Rx5HHXFEa75oGK20cEdAAgn14H5f5nGeq6QgcSyLPrWcg1.JvjXbhrN/
> realname: Ubuntu user
> username: ubuntu
> ```

Although what he states is true with regards to his set of scripts, this doesn't have to be the case. The reason the *user* and *password* have no effect is because `cloud-init` is not installed. By default, it's installed in a Server installation, but not a Desktop installation. (Remember, this technique and set of scripts is installing `filesystem.squashfs`, not `ubuntu-server-minimal.squashfs` or `ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.squashfs`.) Therefore, *user* and *password* can be made to work by installing `cloud-init` into the Desktop filesystem, thus avoiding `gnome-initial-setup` from prompting you during first boot to create the default initial user. This can be done in two ways:

- One is with a late-command in your `user-data` file as follows:

  ```
   late-commands:
   - curtin in-target --target=/target -- apt-get install -y cloud-init
  ```
- The other is by chrooting into the unsquashed `filesystem.squashfs` and installing it via your custom script, similar to the tutorial you provided a link to. Since you want an offline installation, I'd simply install it early on into `filesystem.squashfs`.

---

More info and inspiration can be found at the following links:

- [Ubuntu Autoinstall Generator](https://github.com/covertsh/ubuntu-autoinstall-generator)
- [Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy) autoinstall over PXE](https://www.molnar-peter.hu/en/ubuntu-jammy-netinstall-pxe.html)
- [Using Ubuntu Live-Server to automate Desktop installation](https://github.com/canonical/autoinstall-desktop)
- [LiveCDCustomization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization)
- [Automated Server installer config file reference](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference)
- [curtin documentation](https://curtin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: I've tried to create the autoinstall following your instructions and succeeded to do so. Thank you so much for your help! I greatly appreciate it.